# How do you say hello to a couple (man and woman) formally?

Tags: formality, greetings

How do you say hello to a couple (man and woman) formally? If it's a man, we say "hello sir", but how about a couple?

Comment: Just say hello. If addressing a large group of men and women, you could say "Ladies and gentlemen".

Comment: The equivalent of sir is, in AmE, ma’am.

Comment: If it's a married couple, you can say, "Hello, Mr. and Mrs. X". Otherwise, you might say, "Hello, Sir, Madam (or Ma'am)".